# How do I print a line after a return statement?

Tags: c++

My code is something like this:

```
const bool DEBUG = true; 
int number; 

int function1(int number, bool debug){
  do{
     steps++ 
     if(DEBUG==true)cout << "line"<< endl; 
  }while(condition); 
  return steps; 
}

int main(){
  cin >> number; 
  function1(number, DEBUG); 
}
```

I want to print steps first before printing "line" but I'm struggling to figure out how to do that. So basically I want the output to look like

```
steps 
line
```

Per the rules of my assignment I can't change what the return value is and I also can't use arrays. How do I go about this?

Comment: You need to buffer output and print in your desired order.

Comment: Where did you output return value of `function1`?

Comment: Please explain why the seemingly obvious `if(DEBUG==true)cout << "steps" << endl << "line"<< endl;`is not the solution.